# Keras layers concatenation for non matching shapes

Tags: keras

I have a two datasets of shapes

```py
>>> X_st.shape
(Batch_size,10,34)

>>> X_tim.shape
(Batch_size,10,8)
```

And the following model

```py
from tensorflow.keras import layers,Input,Model

# Branch 1 for X_st
Input1 = Input(shape = (10,34) ,name='stat')
Dense1 = layers.Dense(35,activation='relu')(Input1)

# Branch 2 for X_tim
Input2 = Input(shape = (10,8) ,name='tim')
RNN1 = layers.LSTM(10)(Input2)

# Concatination
concatenated = layers.concatenate([Dense1 , RNN1 ],axis=-1)
Final = layers.Dense(44,activation='relu')(concatenated)
output = layers.Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(Final)

model = Model([Input1 , Input2], output)
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['acc'])
```

My goal is to combine the outputs of branch 1 and 2 and pass it to `Final` and eventually `output`.

On Running I'm getting the following error

```py
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 10, 35), (None, 10)]
```

Do I have to reshape the outputs to achieve that? if so then how?

Comment: Dense1 is 3d RNN1 is 2d

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Yes ,  so there is no way of combining those layers?

Comment: in this way you can't

Comment: @MarcoCerliani Thanks, do you have any references to the ways it can be done?

Comment: the way to do this simply remain in 3d or 2d... example if u would like to stay in 3d: you have to concatenate two tensors with the same first and second dimension